# How to retrieve pointer to one of multiple UIViews inside a custom TableViewCell?

Tags: uitableview, uiimageview

I have created a custom `UITableViewCell` in Interface Builder and also created a class for it, and loaded it into my `ViewController` by registering its NIB. 
Inside the custom cell I have an `UIImageView`, a `UILabel` and two `IBOutlets` for each of them in my `customViewCell.h`:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *assignmentImageView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *testLabel;
```

Now in the the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, I can write to the label outlet with:

```
cell.testLabel = @"text"
```

But I am unable to set the `image` property of the `cell.assignmentImageView` to some image I want to load. So the following doesn't do anything:

```
cell.assignmentImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"my.png"];
```

I also noticed that the completion feature of xcode doesn't show `assignmentImageView` as a property of `cell`, but it does show `testLabel`. So that leads me to believe that even though `assignmentImageView` has been set as an `IBOutlet`, it is for some reason not considered as such.

I tried also using the `tag` property of the `UIImageView` and retrieve a pointer to the `UIImage` in the cell using the `viewWithTag` method, but that didn't work either.

I know that if I have only a single `UIImage` in the cell, I can reference it with `cell.imageView`, which is strange to me, but I want to be able to have multiple `UIImageView` in the cell and reference them.

Can anyone explain me how to do this?

Thanks

-Malena

Comment: Before setting up the `cell.assignmentImageView.image` property, can you put a breakpoint and check if `cell.assignmentImageView` is not nil please?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check of your `assignmentImageView` outlet is wired with a correct view in `XIB`.
2. Check if the image you are trying to set is added to your project.
3. Set breakpoints or use `NSAssert` or `NSParameterAssert` statements to verify that `UIImage` and the `assignmentImageView` are not `nil`.